# date time picker conditions or values

Tags: vb.net, winforms

just wanna ask how to get the this month, last month, this year and last year on date time picker in vb.net 2012 is it possible? For example I chose "This month" in the combo box, then the date time picker value with change to today's month. here is my code structure..

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    'if "Today" was chosen
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        DateTimePicker1.Value = Today
        DateTimePicker2.Value = Today
        'if "This Month" was chosen
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms program, ASP.NET, or what?

Comment: windows forms program sir.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: oh. ok sorry bout that. It's my first time posting questions here. hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Get Last Month

```
 DateTimePicker1.Value=Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Get Last Year

```
  DateTimePicker1.Value= Now.AddYears(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```